# Complex integral of logarithmic derivative of $\zeta$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

I want to prove that for any $x\geq 2$ we have
$$
\begin{split}
-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s)&=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}\frac{\log(x/n)}{\log x}+\frac{1}{\log x}\left(\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s)\right)^{\prime}+\frac{1}{\log x}\sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho-s}}{(\rho-s)^2}\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad-\frac{x^{1-s}}{(1-s)^2\log x}+\frac{1}{\log x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{-2k-s}}{(2k+s)^2}.
\end{split}
$$
The idea of the proof is to consider to express $\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}$ as a Dirichlet series and make use of the identity (for $c>0$)
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}x^s\frac{ds}{s^2}=
\begin{cases}
\log x &\text{if }x\geq 1,\\
0 &\text{if } 0\leq x <1.
\end{cases}
$$
Indeed in this way, setting $c=\max\{1,2-\sigma\}$ and interchanging the order of summation and integration (which is justified b absolute convergence), we get
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s+w)\frac{x^w}{w^2}\,dw&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^{s+w}}\right]\frac{x^w}{w^2}\,dw\\
        &=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^w\frac{dw}{w^2}\\
        &=\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n^s}\log(x/n).
\end{split}
$$
Now I would to estimate the integral in another way: moving the line of integration to the left ($c\to \infty$) and using Cauchy residue theorem.
The residue I get is
$$ 
-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s)\log x-\left(\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s)\right)^{\prime}-\sum_{\rho}\frac{x^{\rho-s}}{(\rho-s)^2}+\frac{x^{1-s}}{(1-s)^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{-2k-s}}{(2k+s)^2}.
$$
Therefore I would get my claim if I was able to show that the other integrals go to zero. How can I show it? Let
$$
f(w)=-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s+w)\frac{x^w}{w^2}
$$
I have to fix $K>0$ and show that
$$
\int_{c+iK}^{-K+iK}f(w)\,dw,\qquad \int_{-K+iK}^{-K-iK}f(w)\,dw,\qquad \int_{-K-iK}^{c-iK}f(w)\,dw,
$$
all tend to zero as $K\to \infty$. Do you have any hint on how to proceed? Which bound should I use? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use (10.27) in Montgomery-Vaughan and Stirling's formula to bound the second integral, and Lemma 12.2 in Montgomery-Vaughan to bound the first and third integrals.

Comment: Basically I have to follow the proof of Theorem 12.5 in Montgomery-Vaughan to get the claim, right?

Comment: pretty much - basicallu the bottom half of p.401

Comment: great! many thanks!

Comment: btw, do you know where I can find a reference for the identity $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}x^s\frac{ds}{s^2}=
\begin{cases}
\log x &\text{if }x\geq 1,\\
0 &\text{if } 0\leq x <1.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: No idea, but it's a pretty trivial exercise in complex analysis via the residue theorem.

Comment: oh right, it is just the residue of the function at s=0 and then the estimate is similar to the proof of the similar identity used in Perron's formula. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that either @Peter or asd post an answer based on these comments.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Peter we can prove the claim as follows. We will use of the following results from the book "Multiplicative Number Theory, I" by Montgomery-Vaughan.

> **Lemma 12.2**   For each real number $T\geq 2$ there is a $T_1$ with $T\leq T_1\leq T+1$ such that $$
> \frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(\sigma+iT_1)\ll(\log T)^2
> $$
>   uniformly for $-1\leq \sigma\leq 2$.

and

> **Lemma 12.4** Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the set of points of $s\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sigma\leq -1$ and $|s+2k|\geq 1/4$ for every positive integer $k$. Then
>   $$
> \frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s)\ll\log(|s|+1)
> $$
>   uniformly for $s\in\mathcal{A}$.

Using these two results we proceed as follows (basically following the proof of **Theorem 12.5** in the same book): let $K$ be a positive integer and consider the contour of integration consisting of the line segments connecting
$$
c-iT_1,\quad -K-iT_1,\quad -K+iT_1,\quad c+iT_1
$$
Moreover we split the horizontal segments
$$
[-K\pm iT_1,\,c\pm iT_1]
$$
in
$$
[-K\pm iT_1,\,-1-\Re(s)\pm iT_1]\cup [-1-\Re(s)\pm iT_1,\,c\pm iT_1]
$$
Since $|\sigma+iT_1|\geq T$, by Lemma 12.2 if follows that
$$
\int_{-1-\Re(s)\pm iT_1}^{c\pm iT_1}-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s+w)\frac{x^w}{w^2}\,dw\ll\frac{(\log T)^2}{T^2}\int_{-1-\Re(s)}^{c}x^{\sigma}d\sigma\ll\frac{x(\log T)^2}{T^2 \log x}
$$
which goes to 0 as $T\to \infty$. Similarly, by Lemma 12.4 we have
$$
\int_{-K\pm iT_1}^{-1-\Re(s)\pm iT_1}-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s+w)\frac{x^w}{w^2}\,dw\ll \frac{\log T}{T^2}\int_{-K}^{-1-\Re(s)}x^{\sigma}d\sigma\ll\frac{\log T}{T^2}\int_{-\infty}^{-1}x^{\sigma}d\sigma\\ \ll\frac{\log T}{xT^2 \log x}
$$
which again tends to 0 as $T\to \infty$. It remains to bound the vertical segment. Using again Lemma 12.4 and subsadditivity of the logarithm, we get
$$
\int_{-K-iT_1}^{-K+iT_1}-\frac{\zeta^{\prime}}{\zeta}(s+w)\frac{x^w}{w^2}\,dw\ll\frac{\log (K+T)}{K^2}x^{-K}\int_{-T_1}^{T_1}1\,dt\ll\frac{T\log KT}{K^2x^K}
$$
which tends to 0 as $K\to \infty$, proving our claim.